# Custom Bridge in Ubuntu 16.04 with LXD

Tags: ubuntu, networking, lxc, bridge, lxd

**Problem**

I am using two NICs on a host on which I want to run LXD with the Docker profile. I have DNSMASQ running on interface 0 (enp0s10f0) and loopback. I want LXD containers to use a separate NIC (enp0s10f1). At this time I don't need the containers to be exposed on the network directly. So I created a bridge (lxdbr1) manually in /etc/network/interfaces with enp0s10f0 as it's slave. I want to use ebtables + DNSMASQ with a custom configuration (which may change for different container instances) to filter allowed outbound traffic from the container. I am trying to not use the lxd-bridge service and the default bridge (lxdbr0) that it creates because of my requirements above.

I am faced with two problems now:

1. I attached lxdbr1 to the default LXD profile. If I launch a container with the default and docker profiles, I do see a eth0 interface within the container. However, this is has no IPv4 address and seems to have a random IPv6 addresses. I believe this is because this is the default setup that LXD does. I tried editing the network configuration with lxc device edit lxdbr1 but after adding the ipv4.address, ipv4.nat, ipv6.address and ipv6.nat options and saving the file, the edit command indiates an error with "Config parse error: not found". I verified that the YAML I wrote is correct with a formatter. So not sure what the problem here is.
2. Assuming I am able to get the above working, do I need to anything beyond that? The Debian networking wiki on masquerading indicates I have to also setup default routes from the external network IP on interface enp0s10f1 to the internal IP allocated to the bridge. This part also is confusing to me.

Are there any other simpler options? Can I for example use the default bridge created by LXD, make that persistent and then use my own DNSMASQ instances (I might have multiple ones) and my own traffic rules?

**Background**

I am working on building out a continuous delivery pipeline for teams shipping services or libraries on Linux. For various reasons, we have to lock down the host and environment in which the build, sign and publish processes run while providing the teams using the pipeline maximum flexibility to use any programming language, frameworks or tools as they see fit. For example, let's say a team wants to use Haskell and Rust (for whatever reason) at versions A and B; I do not want to be in the business of managing such declarations or pre-installing them for that team. At the same time, I want to ensure that they do not use random package sources or end up publishing unsigned packages. So I have come up with a solution that may work that uses ephemeral LXD containers (with Docker within) for different stages (build, test, package, publish, archive) with any work required by the pipeline 
being done in-between on the host before start or after start of each container. The workflow will be something like:

- Do pre-build steps on host.
- Invoke user build script within container.
- Do post-build steps on host.
- Do pre-test steps on host.
- Invoke user test script within container.
- Invoke post-test steps on host.

And so on.

Answer (score 1):

By attaching the containers to a bridge that contains a physical network interface, you are in fact directly exposing the containers to that network, that's what a bridge does.

If you don't want the containers exposed at the layer-2 level to your physical network, then create a bridge which does not contain your physical network. You can then run dnsmasq on that bridge so the containers can get an IP address and the host will act as a gateway.